# directshow disable activemovie window in C++ console application

Tags: c++, command-line, visual-studio-2005, console, directshow

I am creating a video frame output program in a c++ console application using direct show. I have the video loading in and playing fine, however, the video pops up in an ActiveMovie Window. Is there any way I can possibly disable this that way I can just output frame information to the command line window? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of frame information do you want to output to the console? To not have the ActiveMovie video popup, you could just use the null renderer filter.

Comment: I am trying to play a video in the background and display frame information as it process through it. I don't need it to display the video; just the information about it.